# PHP Gif GD Libraries Animation Loss Only First Frame Shown

Tags: php, gd, libraries, gif, animated

I'm having a problem with GD Libraries.

When I use `imagecreatefromgif` or stuff like that, with an already-animated gif, I just get a single frame to be displayed. No animation so.

I've tried everything it's on the web without results. Do you know a way to just show correctly the animation of a GIF with GD Libraries? It's just frustrating when I see those images stuck without animation...

Answer (score 0):

While I  personally have never come across them, the GD library is said to have some GIF support for *creating* animated GIF files. From the [FAQ](http://www.boutell.com/gd/faq.html):

> Yes. Support for GIF was restored in gd 2.0.28 on July 21st, 2004. Support for creating GIF animations is also available. Note that gdlib-config --features can be used to list the image formats supported by gd. Versions of gdlib-config prior to recent updates do not support the --features option, which can be understood to mean that GIF is not available.

However, as far as I know, it has no capabilities to *read* animated GIFs.

You will have to turn to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) if you want to [process animated GIFs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with GD. The way to do it is to have [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) installed (on the server). Then you shell out a command to that to do what you want.

E.g., to resize an animated gif:

```
exec('convert ' . escapeshellarg($originalfile) . ' -coalesce -resize ' . $width . 'x' . $height . ' -layers optimize ' . escapeshellarg($newfile));
```

See also: [[1]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), [[2]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

May be you'd like to check [SVGDreams library](http://www.svgdreams.com/). It's an SVG animation library with ajax and keyboard support.